# ¿Qué significa "x for x" en Python?

Tags: python, bucle-for

estoy aprendiendo Python. Tengo una duda con esta sentencia:

`x for x in` , principalmente por la primera `x` antes del `for`. ¿Qué significa, como y cuando usarla?

Saludos para todos

Comment: Se llama comprehension, es solo una forma rápida de escribir un `for` tradicional. Puedes verlo en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) y también en preguntas creadas [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+comprension).

Comment: Es `x for x in iterable`. La parte `x in iterable` dice de donde salen los elementos. El `x`a solas es en realidad cualquier expresión que contenga `x`. Podría ser, por ejemplo, `abs(x) for x in [-1, 3, -4, 2]`.

Comment: super claro! muchas gracias!